# How do i change the css depending upon the season set in php?

Tags: php, css, session, authentication

On my webpage i have given a login button. But i just want remove that button  and keep other layout and design  same if the user is logged in and the session is set. How do i connect php with css? I also want to include a drop down menu in place of that login button.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your PHP.

You probably have a user class or script that makes you check if the user is logged in. You can use that. If the user is logged in, show the dropdown, if not, show the login form.

```
<?php
if( $user->login == true ) {
    /* user is logged in */
    echo '<select><option>Dropdown option 1</option><option>Dropdown option 2</option></select>';
}
else {
    /* user is NOT logged in */
    echo 'Username: <input type="text" />';
    echo 'Password: <input type="password" />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use php variables in javascript snippet; so this could help:

[Use a PHP variable in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668311/use-a-php-variable-in-jquery)