# How to include a PHP variable in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oJ4C.jpg "html code"
[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Ug0.jpg "php code"

I try to use the variables from php in javascript to generate a chart with them.

Comment: past code into your question as text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668311/use-a-php-variable-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try using an id e.g.

In your html
 name='someName'>

Then use that ID in your JS.

Answer (score -1):

Use can use something like this:

```
var data = '<?=$dataFromPhp?>';
```